# jQuery doesn't persist modified anchor tag href attribute

Tags: jquery, anchor

I'm trying to modify anchor tag href ausing jQuery as per below, but I couldn't persist the changes I made into htmlFragment below.

It seems like jQuery selector copies the value, rather than uses the reference?

**Can I save the modified href value without copying into a new element ?**

```
 <div class="photo"><a class="photo_large" href=http://myimage/a/1.jpg>AAAA</a></div> 
 <div class="photo"><a class="photo_large" href=http://myimage/b/1.jpg>AAAA</a></div>   

function(err, htmlFragment) {
    var photosImg = $('.photo_large', htmlFragment);

    $(photosImg[0]).attr('href', '');
    $(photosImg[1]).attr('href', '');
    $(photosImg[2]).attr('href', '');

    $('#mydivout').html( htmlFragment );
}
```

Comment: I dont see changes being made to htmlFragment here, and copies what value, reference to what?

Comment: Although your code can be greatly improved, it seems to do what you want (emptying the `attr` attribute): http://jsfiddle.net/Frerc/. Please be more precise about your problem. If we cannot replicate it, we cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks Felix, the htmlFragment in my code wasn't a jQuery object, just a normal DOM elem, that's why it didn't work. :)
Wrapping it as jQuery object makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I have to wrap normal DOM elem into JQuery

```
    var normalDom = document.getElementById('myelem');

    var photosImg = $('.photo_large', $(normalDom) );
```

Otherwise jQuery won't save any modified data back into DOM.

I can't reproduce what I got in jsFiddle for unknown reason, i got it working on my system.

Answer (score 0):

WIth whatever you have explaind I'm trying to answer you

```
$("a.photo_large").each(function(index,value){
  $(this).attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
});
```

In above code the `index` will give you the position of the `a` starting from 0, If you to perform something special for any link then you can do it by using the `index`

Comment: thanks, it didn't work because i didn't wrap my element into jQuery object as per my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the values of your href you could always use something like this:

```
$(photosImg[0]).href = $(photosImg[0]).href.replace("old value","new value");
```

or

```
 $(photosImg[0]).href = $(photosImg[0]).href.replace($(photosImg[0]).href,"new value");
```

And if you want to do it to more then one , such as your example, you could use a for loop;.

Comment: thanks, it didn't work because i didn't wrap my element into jQuery object as per my answer